# HTML5 : Start counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am using a template where there is counter css class, which as the name suggests counts to given number with incremental effect.

Here is the code,

```
<div class="counter"><span id="emi" data-from="100" data-to="12835" data-refresh-interval="50" data-speed="5000">12835</span></div>
```

So this works when I load page. It counts from 100 to 12835 with counter effect. But I need to change that value, `12835` and restart the counter.

Is there anyway I can restart that effect. By default it works without any method to call, on page load.

So my another question is how page load can call that counter? [That might give me a clue where should I look]

http://themes.semicolonweb.com/html/canvas/counters.php

My Code:

```
// assume
var emi = 10000;

$("#emi").hide();
$("#emi").html(emi);
$("#emi").removeAttr("class");


$("#emi").parent().attr("class", "counter");
$("#emi").attr("data-from", "100");
$("#emi").attr("data-to", emi);
$("#emi").attr("data-refresh-interval", "50");
$("#emi").attr("data-speed", "5000");
$("#emi").show();
```

If i remove `$("#emi").html(emi);` its not updating anything in html, there is still a previous value in `#emi`. So working on that.

Comment: Can you include to documentation at Question ? What should number be changed to ? Is expected result for counter to be called twice ? _"So this works when I load page. It counts from 100 to 12835 with counter effect"_ Can you create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: Just use javascript and modify the data-to attribute...?

Comment: yes isn't there a documentation ?? or example code?

Comment: @LukePark Yeah but it only changes a number, without counter effect.

Comment: @guest271314 I have posted a link. In their documentation which I got when I purchased, they have only stated `data-from`, `data-to` and other attributes but no start stop. Very limited info. I have very little idea of html5, can that be handled in html5? or is it js library?

Comment: @user3526 Yes, should be possible to achieve effect using `html` , `javascript`

Comment: What is purpose of `data-refresh-interval="50"` ?

Comment: @guest271314 Not sure. Looks like increment value to me.

Comment: @guest271314 http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/js/functions.js
They have `SEMICOLON.widget.counter()` and `SEMICOLON.widget.runCounter(t,i)` Tried calling both with `$("#emi").counter()` but says not found. How to call them?! Or is it only for internal use?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that plugin gives you ability to restart itself, so you would need to hack into it. But here's a self made demo, you could play-around and improve it for your own needs. Anyway it should help to understand how to make plugins

```js
function Counter(selector) {
  var self = this;

  //get all props from element
  this.elem = document.querySelector(selector);
  this.from = parseInt(this.elem.getAttribute('data-from') || 100);
  this.to = parseInt(this.elem.getAttribute('data-to') || 1000);
  this.refreshInterval = parseInt(this.elem.getAttribute('data-refresh-interval') || 50);
  this.speed = parseInt(this.elem.getAttribute('data-speed') || 5000);

  
  //start counter
  //if restart(int) is provided
  //restart counter after finishing with timeout
  this.start = function(restart) {
    //base logic, can be improved
    var diff = self.to - self.from;
    var steps = self.speed / self.refreshInterval;
    var step = diff / steps;
    var i = 1;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      var change = step * i;
      if (change <= self.to) {
        self.elem.textContent = Math.round(change);
        i++;
      } else {
        self.elem.textContent = Math.round(self.to)
        clearInterval(interval);
        //try to restart counter
        if(restart && restart > 0){
          setTimeout(function(){
            self.start(restart);
          }, restart);
        }
      }
    }, self.refreshInterval);
  }
}

//example1
var counter = new Counter('#emi');
//restart after 2000ms
counter.start(2000);

//example2
var counter2 = new Counter('#emi2');
//dont restart
counter2.start(0);
```

```html
<span id="emi" data-from="100" data-to="12835" data-refresh-interval="50" data-speed="1000"></span>

<span id="emi2" data-from="100" data-to="1000" data-refresh-interval="100" data-speed="1000"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using jQuery `.animate()` , `.data()` , `.promise()`

Note, not certain of expected affect of `data-refresh-interval="50"` ?

```js
$.fx.interval = 0;
var el = $("#emi");

function counter(elem) {

return $({
  from: elem.data().from
}).animate({
  from: elem.data().to
}, {
  easing:"linear",
  duration: elem.data().speed,
  step: function(now, fx) {    
    elem
    .text(Math.floor(now))
  }
}).promise().then(function() {
  return elem
})
  
}

counter(el).then(function(_elem) {
  // `_elem` : `this`
  // restart `counter` with new options set at `elem` : `_elem` : `this`
  counter(this.data({from:100, to:10000, refreshInterval:100, speed:5000}));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="counter"><span id="emi" data-from="100" data-to="12835" data-refresh-interval="50" data-speed="5000"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Well I tried all the methods and its still not working. Your code is a little hard for me, working on that. Meanwhile I am editing question to add more details about what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the counters work in such a way that they start on a page load and stop when they reach the given number, in your case 12835. Could you please specify what you're trying to achieve with a counter what runs endlessly?
All the counters on http://themes.semicolonweb.com/html/canvas/counters.php have a specified end point, until it is a countdown counter, but they also have an end point.
If you could provide the specification of `class="counter"` in your CSS it might help figuring out the way to solve your problem. But again, what is the initial reason for implementing such functionality?
If you want to get your website visitor attention to this, then perhaps you can make the counter run slower or enlarge the initial number. 
The code you've provided is not MVP.

Comment: I have a calculator, where as soon as you start typing it calculates EMI. So if you enter P, R and N, it will count EMI. Here I need effect. Now when you changed any of N, R, P value, I want to increase / decrease the EMI value with effect, comparing to previous value. Problem is when I put counter dynamically via jquery, its not functioning as expected. Not looks like a counter, just a simple number.